# I am trying to build a website that has a file manager on it. Is there any way to pull file paths and files from Google Drive?

Tags: html, google-drive-api

I would also like to pull from Dropbox, Box, and iCloud Drive. If there is no way, I will try to work around it but I was just wondering. I would like to be able to see the whole drive (all files and folders accessible). Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the apis? Google drive provides api to access the files and directories after permission from user

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you exactly are looking to do, you can use [Google Drive's API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-sdk) to create/open files on your Drive for a serious project. If you are just experimenting with an idea, you can [host your site directly from Google Drive](https://thenextweb.com/google/2013/02/05/google-drive-now-lets-developers-share-hosted-websites-by-storing-html-javascript-and-css-files/#).

Comment: Hi, I wanted to be able to see the whole file directory - every file and folder. is this possible?

Comment: @NathanielSmith You would have to look into using the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/about/get) to do a `GET request` on the top level folder you are trying to view the contents of.

Answer (score 0):

To display all the files including folders, use [Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list). If you want to specify which type of file you want to show, check [Search Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters).

To know more about working with folders and filepaths check [Work with Folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder)